# Apache Spark with Spring Cloud

Tags: apache-spark, cloud, spring-cloud, apache-spark-mllib, bigdata

Is there a way to integrate Apache Spark with Spring Cloud? Just started working on this area and any tutorials or blogs would be really helpful.

Comment: spring-cloud is pretty broad, from discovery and configuration to data flow and stream. What part are you asking about specifically?

Comment: So I currently have a Spring Cloud environment setup with a discovery server, a config server and client applications that interact with each other. I am trying to run an Apache Spark MLlib algorithm on one of my  client applications to perform clustering on a dataset that is stored on HDFS. But I am unsure of how to call Spark from a Spring Cloud Client application

Comment: I know very little about Spark. A Spring Cloud app is just a Boot app so however you would normally do it from java would be the right approach.

Comment: Hi Spencer, thank you so much! That was what I concluded as well. Trying it right now.